# Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/sys/class/gpio/export' on Rpi Zero with Node-RED on Docker

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red, gpio

I'm running a Node-RED container on Rpi Zero in order to use the rpi-led-control library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-led-control) but I am unable to use it because I get this error:

`Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/sys/class/gpio/export'`

I'm currently running the container in this way:

`docker run -d -p 1880:1880 --group-add dialout --device=/dev/spidev0.0 --device=/dev/spidev0.1 --device=/dev/serial0 --user=root --restart=always -e NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=256" --log-opt max-file=2 --log-opt max-size=2k -e TZ="Europe/Rome" braghettos/node-red:latest`

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM nodered/node-red:latest

USER root

RUN npm install node-red-node-serialport xbee-api node-red-contrib-xbee node-red-node-pi-gpiod node-red-contrib-telegrambot node-red-contrib-python-function node-red-node-twitter node-red-contrib-function-npm node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot onoff rpi-led-control node-red-contrib-play-audio

COPY ./config/settings.js /data/

RUN mkdir /cert

COPY ./cert/cert.pem /cert
COPY ./cert/key.pem /cert

RUN apk update && apk add py-pip \
        && pip install requests plotly --upgrade
```

What I want to do is to interact with the SPI pins of the Rpi Zero GPIO from the Node-RED container.

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount gpio files/filesystem from the host during `docker run` like this:

```
docker run -d -p 1880:1880 
    -v /sys/devices/platform/soc/20200000.gpio:/sys/devices/platform/soc/20200000.gpio \
    -v /sys/class/gpio:/sys/class/gpio \
...
```

The exact file names varies for each Rpi device types, this if for Rpi Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use the docker run [--privileged flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) to give the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside containers on the host:

```
docker run --privileged -d -p 1880:1880 --group-add dialout --device=/dev/spidev0.0 --device=/dev/spidev0.1 --device=/dev/serial0 --user=root --restart=always -e NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=256" --log-opt max-file=2 --log-opt max-size=2k -e TZ="Europe/Rome" braghettos/node-red:latest
```